# Variable in Quotes in Postgres Query

Tags: php, postgresql, quotes

This is probably a stupid question, but I have been Googling an answer for the better part of the day and can't get anywhere. I am trying to get the following bit of code to work, but can't find any help on how to properly format a prepared Postgres request in PHP.

```
$foo = $_GET[bar];    

echo $foo; // 5555

//what I'm trying to do:
pg_prepare($dbconn,"table_query","SELECT Members FROM programs WHERE programID = '$1' ");
pg_execute($dbconn,"table_query", array($foo));
```

If I hardcode the statement with a value, it works fine, but only if I include the single quotes. I've tried just about every method I can find to escape the single quotes or append the quotes to the string, but all I can get are parsing errors.

What totally obvious thing am I missing?

**Edit**: Changed the snippet to clarify that the variable I am getting does not include quotes. Any method I where I try to add the quotes fails.

Answer (score 2):

Let’s study a complete example. Suppose you got your value from a GET query which set the name `pid`. From your example query I expect the value to be the decimal representation of an integer, different from zero. It is a string, since nothing else can come from a GET query.

```
 $pid = $_GET['pid'];

 // This is _very_ important.
 // Anything that comes from outside must be validated or sanitized.
 // FILTER_VALIDATE_INT refuses "0" too (correct if needed).
 if (filter_var($pid, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT) === false) {
   // Deal with invalid input 
 }

 $result = pg_query_params($dbconn,
     'SELECT Members FROM programs WHERE programID = $1',
     array($pid)
 );
```

`pg_query_params` binds `$1` with `$pid` and quotes it correctly, while you cannot use double quotes around the statement because PHP would expand `$1` incorrectly. There is no need to put quotes around `$pid` manually, because `pg_query_params` takes care of this. Furthermore, PostgreSQL accepts an integer value both with quotes and without them, so fumbling with quotes is pointless in this case.

Instead of using the traditional `pg_` functions, you might use `PDO`, the PHP Database Object abstraction layer.
In that case (disregarding possible options needed in your case):

```
  $dsn = 'pgsql:host='. $host .';port=5432;dbname='. $database;
  $dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
  $dbh->prepare('SELECT Members FROM programs WHERE programID = ?');
  $result = $dbh->execute(array($pid)); // $pid as before
```

Comment: A little extra explanation about why you're using `$1` rather than the erroneous `'$1'` inside the SQL string might be helpful and might help fend off people that don't understand how `pg_query_params` works. Just a small suggestion.

Comment: In your example, the value of foo already has quotes around it. My function uses GET and draws a value of $foo without quotes. So I think I need to rephrase my question on how to properly add quotes around the value. My attempts to convert it to a string and append single quotes doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @AdamAndrews I have substantially expanded my answer. I hope everything is clearer now.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using prepared statements.  This should solve your quoting problem and also remove a major risk of SQL injection.  Try something like this:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT Members FROM programs WHERE programID = ?");
$stmt->bind_param("s", $foo);

$foo = "5555";
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I thought I was already using a prepared statement. Should I change methods?

Comment: @AdamAndrews: AFAIK you are using a prepared statement because [`pg_query_params`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pg-query-params.php) appears to be a very thin wrapper around the PostgreSQL C API, that also means that you free from injection problems. Not a PHP guy but I'd guess that PHP will try to interpolate that `$1` placeholder in a double quoted string (hence Dario's single quotes) and `'$1'` is a string literal  in SQL whereas `$1` is a numbered placeholder (hence the unquoted `$1` in Dario's).